# How to split data in SQL Server table row

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, t-sql

I have table of transaction which contains a column `transactionId` that has values like `|H000021|B1|`.

I need to make a join with table `Category` which has a column `CategoryID` with values like `H000021`.

I cannot apply join unless data is same.

So I want to split or remove the unnecessary data contained in `TransctionId` so that I can join both tables.

Kindly help me with the solutions.

Comment: What is the actual values of |H000021|B1| whether | is also a part of that number.

Comment: Even if you use `STRING_SPLIT` or another technique to extract the values performance will suffer because no indexes on `transactionID` can be used. You should either fix the bad design or add a computed column that extracts the `categoryID` and cover it with an index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fix your data so the columns are the same.  But sometimes we are stuck with other people's bad design decisions.  In particular, the transaction data should contain a column for the category -- even if the category is part of the id.

In any case:

```
select . . .
from transaction t join
     category c
     on transactionid like '|' + categoryid + |%';
```

Or if the category id is always 7 characters:

```
select . . .
from transaction t join
     category c
     on categoryid = substring(transactionid, 2, 7)
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a computed column with the code only.

Initial scenario:

```
create table Transactions
(
 transactionId varchar(12) primary key,
 whatever varchar(100)
)

create table Category
(
  transactionId varchar(7) primary key,
  name varchar(100)
)

insert into Transactions 
select'|H000021|B1|', 'Anything'

insert into Category 
select 'H000021', 'A category'
```

Add computed column:

```
alter table Transactions add transactionId_code as substring(transactionid, 2, 7) persisted
```

Join using the new computed column:

```
select *
from Transactions t
inner join Category c on t.transactionId_code = c.transactionId
```

Get a straighforward query plan:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using query :

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable  
(PrimaryKey   int PRIMARY KEY,  
   KeyTransacFull      varchar(50) 
  );  
GO  

CREATE TABLE #MyTransaction 
(PrimaryKey   int PRIMARY KEY,  
   KeyTransac      varchar(50) 
  );  
GO  

INSERT INTO #MyTable 
SELECT 1, '|H000021|B1|'

INSERT INTO #MyTable 
SELECT 2, '|H000021|B1|'


INSERT INTO #MyTransaction 
SELECT 1, 'H000021'


SELECT * FROM #MyTable

SELECT * FROM #MyTransaction

SELECT * 
FROM #MyTable 
JOIN #MyTransaction ON KeyTransacFull LIKE '|'+KeyTransac+'|%' 

DROP TABLE  #MyTable

DROP TABLE  #MyTransaction
```